# How to inject JWT in service generated by NSwag Studio in react wih typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, http-headers

I am using NSwag Studio to generate service class in react using typescript.
Here is an example of the generated code:

```
export class BookingClient {
    private http: { fetch(url: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit): Promise<Response> };
    private baseUrl: string;
    protected jsonParseReviver: ((key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined = undefined;

    constructor(baseUrl?: string, http?: { fetch(url: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit): Promise<Response> }) {
        this.http = http ? http : <any>window;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl ? baseUrl : "";
    }

    getMarinaData(model: MarinaDataRequest): Promise<MarinaDataResponse> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/booking/marina/data";
        url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

        const content_ = JSON.stringify(model);

        let options_ = <RequestInit>{
            body: content_,
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json", 
                "Accept": "application/json"
            }
        };

        return this.http.fetch(url_, options_).then((_response: Response) => {
            return this.processGetMarinaData(_response);
        });
    }

    protected processGetMarinaData(response: Response): Promise<MarinaDataResponse> {
        const status = response.status;
        let _headers: any = {}; if (response.headers && response.headers.forEach) { response.headers.forEach((v: any, k: any) => _headers[k] = v); };
        if (status === 200) {
            return response.text().then((_responseText) => {
            let result200: any = null;
            result200 = _responseText === "" ? null : <MarinaDataResponse>JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver);
            return result200;
            });
        } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
            return response.text().then((_responseText) => {
            return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
            });
        }
        return Promise.resolve<MarinaDataResponse>(<any>null);
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I add or inject JWT for protected endpoints. Suppose that not all endpoints are protected.
Thnx for help.

Answer (score 2):

Create a base class and override transformOptions method.

```
export class BaseClass {

    protected transformOptions = async (options: RequestInit): Promise<RequestInit> => {
        let token = getToken(); // your custom logic to get the token

        options.headers = {
            ...options.headers,
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        };
        return Promise.resolve(options);
    };
}
```

And in your nswag.json set:

```
"clientBaseClass": "BaseClass",
"extensionCode": "path/to/your/BaseClass.ts",
"useTransformOptionsMethod": true,
```

This will add it to all endpoints, but I suppose it doesn't hurt to send the token to the non-protected endpoints (it will be ignored).